# Creating and selecting <ol> list elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, list, function, select, dynamic

Is there some devious reason why is this not working?  I’m not an experienced programmer and I am practising creating and selecting elements from a list as the core part of a program I’m creating. This code is intended to create a list called “cats” including a list of numbers 1-10, then the user selects one of the list (say ‘8’) and the list is regenerated starting from 8.  It works the first time but the addEventListener doesn’t seem to work the second time round, even though the list that the event refers to, has already been created.  I would welcome any suggestions.

```js
function listenup() {
  document.getElementById("cats").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    create(e.target.textContent);
  });
}

function create(mycount) {
  var ol = document.createElement("ol");
  ol.setAttribute("id", "cats");
  document.body.appendChild(ol);
  var tempCount = mycount;
  for (var i = mycount; i <= 10 + (tempCount - 1); i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className = "file";

    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.innerHTML = i;

    li.appendChild(a);
    ol.appendChild(li);
  }
  listenup();
}
create(1);
```

Comment: First thing why are you adding multiple id's with same name. Second if you are adding new element to the dom you have to bind event as well

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please change if needed to what you have

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code

```
function listenup() {
    document.getElementById("cats").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    create(e.target.textContent);
        });
}
```

to

```
function listenup() {
    document.getElementById("cats").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    create(parseInt(e.target.textContent));
        });
}
```

or

```
function listenup() {
    document.getElementById("cats").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    create(parseInt(e.target.innerHTML));
        });
}
```

because you need int argument while your code returns to string value.

Answer (score 0):

Added one if condition in create function so now it will work next time as well

```
function listenup() {
    document.getElementById("cats").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        create(e.target.textContent);
    });
}

function create(mycount) {
    var ol;
    if (!document.getElementById("cats")) {
        var ol = document.createElement("ol");
        ol.setAttribute("id", "cats");
        document.body.appendChild(ol);
    }
    ol = document.getElementById("cats")

    var tempCount = mycount;
    for (var i = mycount; i <= 10 + (tempCount - 1); i++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.className = "file";

        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.innerHTML = i;

        li.appendChild(a);
        ol.appendChild(li);
    }
    listenup();
}
create(1);
```

Comment: so you need second time should work right ?

Answer (score 0):

I would delegate

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container")
container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("li");
  const num = +tgt.textContent;
  console.log("create",num)
  create(num);
});


function create(mycount) {
  var ol = document.createElement("ol");
  container.appendChild(ol); // empty the container before here if you want to REPLACE
  var tempCount = mycount;
  for (var i = mycount; i <= 10 + (tempCount - 1); i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className = "file";

    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.innerHTML = i;

    li.appendChild(a);
    ol.appendChild(li);
  }
}
create(1);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand whether you want to keep updating the same ordered list or create new ones:

#### updating the same ordered list

```js
function createOl(startIndex, itemsLength = 10) {
  // Delete the previous list (if any)
  if (document.getElementById("cats")) {
    document.getElementById("cats").remove();
  }
  
  // Create the new list
  const olEle = document.createElement("ol");
  olEle.setAttribute("id", "cats");
  olEle.setAttribute("start", startIndex); // if you want to keep the list index and the item text aligned
  document.body.appendChild(olEle);

  for (let i = startIndex; i < startIndex + itemsLength; i++) {
    const liEle = document.createElement("li");
    liEle.setAttribute("class", "file");

    const aEle = document.createElement('a');
    aEle.setAttribute("href", "#");
    aEle.innerText = i;
    aEle.addEventListener('click', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      createOl(i);
    });

    liEle.append(aEle);
    olEle.append(liEle);
  }
}

//createOl(1); // uncomment this line if you want to start with a list already visible

document.getElementById('resetOl').addEventListener('click', () => createOl(1));
```

```html
<button id="resetOl">
  create / reset OL
</button>
```

#### creating new ordered lists

```js
function createOl(startIndex, itemsLength = 10, readonly = false) {
  const olEle = document.createElement("ol");
  if (!readonly) olEle.setAttribute("class","duplicateOl");
  olEle.setAttribute("start",startIndex); // if you want to keep the list index and the item text aligned
  document.body.appendChild(olEle);
  
  for (let i = startIndex; i < startIndex + itemsLength; i++) {
    const liEle = document.createElement("li");
    liEle.setAttribute("class","file");
    
    const aEle = document.createElement('a');
    aEle.setAttribute("href","#");
    aEle.innerText = i;
    aEle.addEventListener('click', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      createOl(i);
    });
    
    liEle.append(aEle);
    olEle.append(liEle);
  }
}

createOl(1, undefined, true);

document.getElementById('delOls').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.duplicateOl').forEach(elem => elem.remove());
});
```

```html
<button id="delOls">
  delete added lists
</button>
```

Comment: wow. So many answers, so quickly!   'adding multiple id's with same name' - do you mean the 'cats' name for the <ol> - I needed to have a name to refer to the object. I'm trying the binding bit now...I changed the code to the snippet but it still doesn't work after the second attempt.  I just tried 'updating the same ordered list' and that works brilliantly. I'll have to go away and learn the code!  I haven't commented on everyone's comments but I will mull over all of them to see my best way forwards.  But thanks alot everyone.  Much appreciated

Comment: @killeme, please notice that the "creating new ordered lists" snippet (the second one) uses the `class` attribute, not the `id` one because IDs must be univoque. If you tried using it with duplicate IDs, that is probably the reason why it did not work.

Comment: Yeh.  I get it now.  I do have a problem working out how things happen on a web page and this has helped enormously. It really is just one loop. I also didn't know how to remove the old list so I just intended to write over the other one. (not very professional lol)  Lots of great leaning - I love this site.

Comment: Just read your comment there secan.  Univoque is 'unambiguous'.  I was only working with the same ordered list. But I will spend a little time now exploring the other one. (smile)